# Is it possible to manipulate a has_many through in memory only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, has-many-through

**Platform:** Rails 3

**Requirement:**

A form (`businesses#edit`) that allows a user to submit an update to a `Business` record (`businesses#update`.) When submitted `businesses#update` will not persist the changes to the database but will instead send an email with the new information for manual review.

**How it's accomplished:**

Load the `Business` model, update the properties in memory, pass it to an `ActionMailer`, finish without ever saving the model.

**Problem:**

The `Business` model has a `has_many :business_categories :through :business_categories_businesses` which is a `has_many :business_categories_businesses` and whenever I manipulate the `Business.business_categories` (`@business.business_categories = BusinessCategory.where(:id => params[:business][:business_categories])` for example.) the changes are immediately persisted to the database.

I can not find any way of manipulating that collection in memory only so that it can be passed to an action mailer. In the short-term I'm going to hack it by not doing the assignment and simply pass the new collection of `BusinessCategories` to the ActionMailer to work out itself, but now this is just annoying me and I defer to the collective wisdom of the crowd:

It is possible to manipulate has_many relations in memory only and if so how? Please save my sanity.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Just spent the better part of my day coming to the same conclusion...

Comment: I unfortunately did not ever figure this out. My apologies for the late reply, I don't check SO on a regular basis :(